# QFileDialog opens in new window while adding it to QHBoxLayout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qdialog

My issue is that when I am adding QFileDialog to QVBoxLayout it opens in new window. Below is the code which produces my problem.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QFileDialog, QPushButton, QWidget


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
       super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
       self.setWindowTitle("My own MainWindow")

       self.fileDialog = QFileDialog()

       self.confirmAction = QPushButton("Press me", self)

       mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()

       mainLayout.addWidget(self.fileDialog)
       mainLayout.addWidget(self.confirmAction)
       self.setLayout(mainLayout)
```

Comment: QFileDialog inherits from QDialog, and these elements are created to create a dialog window, so it shows is correct. You could explain what you want to get.

Comment: I want to get as a first item in QVBoxLayout QFileDialog, and as a second item simple QPushButton below QFileDialog.

Comment: My direct question is: why do you want to embed a QFileDialog in your Widget?

Comment: Just for training purpose, I wanted to make such widget which holds QFileDialog and below QPushButton.

Comment: Try my answer and if I help you do not forget to mark it as correct.

Comment: What is your suggestion, because I dont get it?

Comment: Wait a moment, I'll improve my answer.

Comment: Now improve the answer, try running the code and understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop):

> Window flags are a combination of a type (e.g. Qt::Dialog) and zero or
> more hints to the window system (e.g. Qt::FramelessWindowHint).
>
> If the widget had type Qt::Widget or Qt::SubWindow and becomes a
> window (Qt::Window, Qt::Dialog, etc.), it is put at position (0, 0) on
> the desktop. If the widget is a window and becomes a Qt::Widget or
> Qt::SubWindow, it is put at position (0, 0) relative to its parent
> widget.

So these flags are used to vary the behavior of the widget, for example to convert it into a window, a dialog, a tooltip, and so on.

In the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#WindowType-enum) gives the following list:

> **Qt::Widget**: This is the default
> type for QWidget. Widgets of this type are child widgets if they have
> a parent, and independent windows if they have no parent. See also
> Qt::Window and Qt::SubWindow.
>
> **Qt::Window**: Indicates that the
> widget is a window, usually with a window system frame and a title
> bar, irrespective of whether the widget has a parent or not. Note that
> it is not possible to unset this flag if the widget does not have a
> parent.
>
> **Qt::Dialog** :Window    Indicates that the widget is a
> window that should be decorated as a dialog (i.e., typically no
> maximize or minimize buttons in the title bar). This is the default
> type for QDialog. If you want to use it as a modal dialog, it should
> be launched from another window, or have a parent and used with the
> QWidget::windowModality property. If you make it modal, the dialog
> will prevent other top-level windows in the application from getting
> any input. We refer to a top-level window that has a parent as a
> secondary window.
>
> **Qt::Sheet**: Window Indicates that the
> window is a Macintosh sheet. Since using a sheet implies window
> modality, the recommended way is to use QWidget::setWindowModality(),
> or QDialog::open(), instead.
>
> **Qt::Drawer**: Window    Indicates
> that the widget is a Macintosh drawer.
>
> **Qt::Popup** : Window    Indicates that the widget is a pop-up top-level window, i.e.
> that it is modal, but has a window system frame appropriate for pop-up
> menus.
>
> **Qt::Tool**: Window  Indicates that the widget is a
> tool window. A tool window is often a small window with a smaller than
> usual title bar and decoration, typically used for collections of tool
> buttons. If there is a parent, the tool window will always be kept on
> top of it. If there isn't a parent, you may consider using
> Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint as well. If the window system supports it, a
> tool window can be decorated with a somewhat lighter frame. It can
> also be combined with Qt::FramelessWindowHint.
>
> On Mac OS X, tool windows correspond to the Floating class of windows.
> This means that the window lives on a level above normal windows; it
> impossible to put a normal window on top of it. By default, tool
> windows will disappear when the application is inactive. This can be
> controlled by the Qt::WA_MacAlwaysShowToolWindow attribute.
>
> **Qt::ToolTip**:Window    Indicates that the widget is a
> tooltip. This is used internally to implement tooltips.
>
> **Qt::SplashScreen**: Window  Indicates that the window is a
> splash screen. This is the default type for QSplashScreen.
>
> **Qt::Desktop**:Window    Indicates that this widget is the
> desktop. This is the type for QDesktopWidget.
>
> **Qt::SubWindow**: Indicates that this widget is a sub-window,
> such as a QMdiSubWindow widget.

In your case we must change the behavior of `Qt::Dialog` to `Qt::Widget`, in the following code I show the code that does it:

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
       super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
       self.setWindowTitle("My own MainWindow")

       self.fileDialog = QFileDialog(self)
       self.fileDialog.setOption(QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
       self.fileDialog.setWindowFlags(Qt.Widget)

       self.confirmAction = QPushButton("Press me", self)

       mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()

       mainLayout.addWidget(self.fileDialog)
       mainLayout.addWidget(self.confirmAction)
       self.setLayout(mainLayout)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Now it is very clear, but which import you make to have Qt.Widget?

Comment: Of course, I will do this. Thank you for clarifying my issue.

Comment: And in separate file I am creating widget and displaying it using
w = MainWindow()

w.show()

Comment: The complete example can be found here: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/7cf200538e182b5662552700c27b998a , Download it and run it, in addition if you observe I have passed to `self` as **parent** of `QFileDialog`

Comment: Code from github also make two separate windows in my case.

Comment: What is your version of pyqt and what is your OS?

Comment: PyQt5, Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Version of pyqt5 and how you installed it, you did it with apt-get or via pip or another method?

Comment: I have tested it in arch linux, PyQt5 5.9.1

Comment: PyQt 5.9, installation via apt-get.

Comment: That I know ubuntu does not have version 5.9 of pyqt, please verify the version correctly, but report the bug to canonical.

Comment: According to what I see in version 5.7: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python-pyqt5&searchon=names , I find it strange that you say 5.9 since ubuntu never uses the latest versions of some software.

Comment: The code from the gist works, but only if it doesn't use a so-called native dialog. On Linux that means you shouldn't run it "as is" under a KDE session or any other session with a Qt integration plugin installed. It will work all the time when you add `self.fileDialog.setOption(QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)` before showing the dialog.

Comment: @RJVB Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this myself, dissatisfied with the "just use non-native dialogs" bit. I've been hacking around in the KDE platform file dialog implementation and have gotten (stuck) pretty close to what I'd want.

The only point of attach I've found is just before the dialog will actually be shown; before that there seems to be no way to know the actual parent widget. But there we can:

- find the parent QWidget (from the parent *QWindow*)
- from that, obtain the (first) (user-side) QFileDialog instance
- if the parent QWidget has a layout, replace the found QFileDialog instance with our own dialog
- save the original user-side QFileDialog instance
- in the dtor, either restore the original QFD in the layout, or call deleteLater() on it (and set it to NULL in case the action causes recursive calling of the dtor).

Glitches:
- dialogs may end up with 2 sets of OK/Cancel/etc. buttons
- if not, these buttons may actually close only the embedded QFD and not the enclosing dialog (seen with the python example linked above)
- resizing works but the saveSize/restoreSize mechanism doesn't
- AFAICT all signals aren't connected properly (the preview in the Scribus open-file dialog doesn't react to selecting a file as it should). File opening does work though.

Full patch here on this BKO ticket:
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=404833#c15

Evidently this is only useful for hackers and software that can ship its own platform theme plugin (which is where the KDE platform file dialog comes from). Fortunately those plugins tend to be relatively small.